# Salesforce CPQ Package Expiration

Tags: appexchange, package

I have installed Salesforce CPQ package in my DEV org and it shows the expiration date as "Does not Expire". Does this mean Salesforce is supporting CPQ package for life time in Developer Edition orgs? I did not find any link/article regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading into it too much.

App Exchange packages can have trial periods and (paid) licences that expire after a period of time (like, say a year).

The lack of an expiration date just means that you don't need to worry about licenses. That's all it means, it doesn't speak to Salesforce's future decisions in any capacity.